# Android Studio, security exception warning

Tags: android

In an Android App I am using following code to make telephone calls:

```
@Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {

                ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = ParseQuery.getQuery("datos_contacto");
                query.whereEqualTo("tipo_contacto", "celular");
                query.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseObject>() {
                    public void done(List<ParseObject> scoreList, ParseException e) {
                        if (e == null) {
                            int len = scoreList.size();
                            for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
                                ParseObject p = scoreList.get(i);
                                String numero = p.getString("dato_contacto");

                                Log.d("score", "Celular: " + numero);

                                Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL, Uri.parse("tel:" + numero));

                                startActivity(intent);

                            }
                        } else {
                            Log.d("score", "Error: " + e.getMessage());
                        }
                    }
                });


            }

        });
```

At line

```
startActivity(intent);
```

the editor shows a red underline, and an error warning:
"Call requires permission which may be rejected by user..."

I can launch the app without exceptions, but I want to remove this warning if possible.

I have included following lines in AndroidManifest:

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />
```

Any help is welcome.

Comment: That happens over/and API 23. Users may reject that permission. You must check that and show a dialog, warning or to tell the user that if he/she rejects that permission, the function will not work.

Comment: @MarianoZorrilla, thanks. The editor proposes to add a line:  if (checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.CALL_PHONE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {.. should I include there a Toast or something similar, telling the user that he/she has rejected the permission to make calls from the app?

Comment: I recommend to check out this article (Link below). It would help you to understand the whole workflow quickly. [Requesting Permissions at Run Time (Android-Developers)](http://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html)

Comment: Exactly! Toast or any other warning :)